# Postgresql selecting all rows which don't have any of a set of values

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-10

I have a table called Meals. Meals have many Components (e.g. mash, brocolli, steak), and each component has_many Allergens.

I want to select the meal(s) which doesn't have any of a given list of allergens.

If I join the three tables, and do allergen_id not in (... list of allergen ids), that will return me the meal if it has any allergen that isn't in the list of allegerns to exclude, which is not right:

```
select * from meals m 
join components c on c.meal_id=c.id 
join allergens a on a.component_id=c.id
where a.id not in (1,2,3,4)
```

If a meal has allergens 1 5 and 7, it will still be returned from the above query. How do I say "return me all meals which don't have any of the following allergens"

*UPDATE* clarifying example.

Say I have a meal made up of Mash, Peas and Pie. Mash has dairy in it, Pie has gluten in it. Then I have a steak meal with a meat allergen in it (no good for vegans).

Mash, Peas, Pie -> Dairy, Gluten

Steak, Chips -> Meat

I want to select the meal or meals which don't have any dairy in them. The result should be the Steak / Chips meal only.

If I join them all:

```
select * from meals m 
join components c on c.meal_id=c.id 
join allergens a on a.component_id=c.id
```

This will give me a row for every allergen. So if I add the where clause:

```
select * from meals m 
join components c on c.meal_id=c.id 
join allergens a on a.component_id=c.id
where a.id not in (2)
```

there will be a row for gluten so Mash / Peas / Pie meal will not be excluded. How do I exclude it?

Comment: Please try to clarify your example by detailing input data and expected output result (maybe with less tables if possible).

Comment: Okay I added some more to try and clarify, does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOT EXISTS(...) does exactly what you want.

Your own text `I want to select the meal(s) which doesn't have any of a given list of allergens.` can almost directly be translated into SQL:

---

```
 -- How do I say:
 -- Return me all meals
select * from meals m
where not exists ( --  which doesn't have 
        select * 
        from  components c  -- any of the following allergens
        join allergens a on a.component_id = c.id AND a.id in (1,2,3,4)
        where c.meal_id = m.id
        );
```

Comment: Oh damn TIL. This is great, I was going down a CTE route that was getting hairy, thank you.